# Pytest: approx() with >, <, <=, and >=

Tags: python, pytest

So [the documentation for pytest states](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-approx) the following:

> **Warning:**
> *Changed in version 3.2.*
>
> In order to avoid inconsistent behavior, TypeError is raised for `>`, `>=`, `<` and `<=` comparisons. The example below illustrates the problem:
>
> ```py
> assert approx(0.1) > 0.1 + 1e-10  # calls approx(0.1).__gt__(0.1 + 1e-10)
> assert 0.1 + 1e-10 > approx(0.1)  # calls approx(0.1).__lt__(0.1 + 1e-10)
> ```
>
> In the second example one expects `approx(0.1).__le__(0.1 + 1e-10)` to be called. But instead, `approx(0.1).__lt__(0.1 + 1e-10)` is used to comparison. This is because the call hierarchy of rich comparisons follows a fixed behavior.

Now I don't know if I'm being stupid, but why would one expect `__le__` in the second example? I definitely don't. I expect `__lt__`.

I don't know what this is trying to state honestly. And I can't see why the functions can't be something like:

```py
def __gt__(self, actual):
    return actual > self.expected and other != self

def __lt__(self, actual):
    return actual < self.expected and other != self
```

with the `__ge__` and `__le__` variants using `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: For reference, this is the original issue inflicting the changes: [#2003](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2003)

Comment: Ah. Thank you for this. I still disagree with his premise of expecting __le__, but that's because he believes `approx` should always be generous towards true, and I disagree with that.

Answer (score 0):

`approx` is meant to be used when you are comparing float type numbers with `==` `!=` operators to avoid the confusing examples of `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`

the provided example should be interpreted like if the user wanted to answer
is `0.1000000001` bigger than `0.1` ? the answer you expect is `True`

now if you use `approx` it would say `False` since `0.1000000001 == approx(0.1)` (if you used `__le__` it would say `True` - that is why they wrote `__le__` is expected)

so using approx - a kind of fuzzy number and greater/less than ranges is not intuitive - questions like is X larger than about 7 are not generally used and if you need a wierd fuzzy ranges you should state it explicitly

Comment: I disagree with the logic. If you want to see if 0.1000000001 is bigger than 0.1 you ONLY expect True if you do not consider 0.1000000001 and 0.1 to be equal. If you consider them approximately equal, then one can't also be approximately larger than the other! This isn't really an issue for me, as I don't plan to use it, but it was confusing.

Comment: Do make this clearer: 0.1 + 0.2 > 0.3 SHOULD be false. Yet python will return True. My idea is that approx would make these equal and thus correctly provide a False result. It's easy to work around (you just check for equality first) but I think the example makes my point more obvious.